# placeholder not showing when my input type = text

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

My placeholder value doesn't show, until i hit the backspace button. Happens only when the input type is text.

```html
 <input type="text" id="name" 
 name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" >

<input type="password" id="Password" 
name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
```

when input type = password it works but whenever I use text it doesn't display until I move the cursor back(press backspace on the field)

Comment: Any CSS that explains that? Can you click the `<>` and create a [mcve] - also try to rename to a non-reserved name - ALSO: give them a value="" !!!

Comment: using the html you provided in fiddle everything worked fine, May be some code is filling your text input with 'space' character?

Comment: Hypothetical lead: you might have some invisible character in your text inputs. Try logging `input.value === ""` to see if it is really empty

Comment: Is there have any css associated with your code?your given html code working perfect in fiddle

Comment: provide CSS related to your HTML inputs http://prntscr.com/fms4fi

Comment: fixed it my value field had {{Request::old('name')}} used in laravel 5.1 instead of just old('name')

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with WordPress and I noted it was erroneously caused by leaving an empty space in the value attribute.

So instead of this : `value="SomeValue "` have it as  `value="SomeValue"`

Notice the empty space after the value seems it is the reason why you have to backspace for the placeholder to be visible. This is the only solution that worked for me.